# Which phrase structure is okay to use?

Tags: grammar, word-order

I wonder if is it okay to use all the below structures in a conversation? Is there any structure I should avoid using? The phrase in this case is `I ate fried chicken`.

> わたしは フライドチキンをたべた。
>   “I fried chicken ate.”
>
> たべた、フライドチキン。
>   “Ate, fried chicken.”
>
> フライドチキンたべた、わたし。
>   “Fried chicken ate, I.”

Which of the above structures you guys use the most? And in what given situations you apply each structure?

Comment: Just as a tip, フライドチキン is a loan word so it should be in katakana in all three sentences =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on contexts.

The first わたしは フライドチキンを たべた is an answer to a question "What did you do/eat?". は after わたし implies presence of plural "you" here. However, if the question is "What would you do?, it's enough possible that singular "you" is asked.

The second たべた。フライドチキン。 is an answer to "Did you eat something?", 
in which you first tell an information that is asked and add supplementary one.

The third フライドチキンたべた。わたし is one to "What did you eat?" or "How did it go?" (Presence of additional わたし makes it lean to this side, and under this question, わたし could take が if it's unexpected for わたし to do so).

Comment: What is the meaning of "*(I'm sorry for wrong post.)*" in the answer?

Comment: I wrongly double-posted.

Comment: @user4092 don't worry about it. Thanks for your explanation so yeah I'll be putting more effort to distinguish each structure for now on.

Answer (score 0):

> わたしは フライドチキンをたべた。This is correct. This is the correct word order of a Japanese sentence.
>
> たべた、フライドチキン。 This is wrong and weird. You should avoid using this.
>
> フライドチキンたべた、わたし。This is wrong and weird. You should avoid using this.

It depends on on what level your Japanese are. However, its obvious that an advanced learner of Japanese would never ask this question. Therefore, I think my answer was simple and said it all for the beginners.　In case that you're an advanced learner who asks this seemingly-very-basic question for some special intention, feel free to ask again!

If Yoda from the movie STAR WARS were Japanese, he might use the second and the third sentence.  ; )

Comment: Haha I recently started to learn japanese, for now on I'll be listening a lot and paying more attention to these details, hopefully soon enough I'll be able to distinguish each phrase and be capable to use them properly in any given situation.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I am serious to say that the second and the third sentence are 99.999% useless in the actual life in Japan. They can be used in  very special occasions such as the character of Yoda. I seriously mean it. When you become a fluent speaker of Japanese, you will know. You will know!